# How can I make my code shorter and keep all functionalities? (Don't repeat yourself)

Tags: python, class, dry

I am working on a program that sorts data using mergesort. I implemented functions to 'Person' class to make it comparable, sortable, subscriptable, iterable, and castable (to float, int, and string). I want to define everything once that no code is repeated - write a dry code. Did I implement some functionality (for example magic method) twice?

How Are there any specific locations that can be shorter? and keep all functionalities at the same time? If so, suggest a change in a specific line.

```
import numpy as np
import load_names
import enum
from merge_sort import mergesort




NAMES = load_names.load_names()  # Variables in the global namespace 


class Person():
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, weight):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
        self._height = height
        self._weight = weight


    #def __len__(self):
        #return len(self.data)



    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self._name}, {self._age} years, {self._height} cm, {self._weight} kg\n"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) == (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) < (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) <= (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) > (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) >= (other._age, other._height, other._weight)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._name}, {self._age} years, {self._height} cm, {self._weight} kg"

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self._name
        elif index == 1:
            return self._age
        elif index == 2:
            return self._weight
        elif index == 3:
            return self._height
        else:
            raise IndexError("Index out of range")

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self._age)

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self._age)

    def to_tuple(self):
        return (self._name, self._age, self._weight, self._height)

    def to_list(self):
        return [self._name, self._age, self._weight, self._height]
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name
    def get_age(self):
        return self._age
    def get_height(self):
        return self._height
    def get_weight(self):
        return self._weight




def create_persons_list(n=10, sort_key='height'):
    
    person_objects = [(Person(np.random.choice(NAMES), np.random.randint(18, 101), np.random.randint(150, 201), np.random.randint(45, 101))) for _ in range(n)]
    #print("po: ",person_objects[0])
    x=Person()
    if sort_key == 'name':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_name())
    elif sort_key == 'age':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_age())
    elif sort_key == 'height':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_height())
    elif sort_key == 'weight':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_weight())
    else:
        return mergesort(person_objects)

# Example usage:
sorted_persons_by_name = create_persons_list(sort_key='name')
sorted_persons_by_age = create_persons_list(sort_key='age')
sorted_persons_by_height = create_persons_list(sort_key='height')
sorted_persons_by_weight = create_persons_list(sort_key='weight')


print("Sorted by height (default): \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_height)
print("Sorted by name: \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_name)
print("Sorted by age: \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_age)
print("Sorted by weight: \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_weight)
print("No key arg:  ", create_persons_list())


#print(create_persons_list())
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To expand on Kenny's comment above -- Stack Overflow is only for _narrow, specific_ questions about problems (in the sense of things that block you from having working code) you can isolate and build a [mre] for. [codereview.se] is better suited to "how do I improve this working code?" questions (though note its other rules: questions there are expected to accept any kind of improvement, not just the specific kind the OP may particularly be asking for).

Comment: Mind, using a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) would do a lot of this for you. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/ describing it -- the example they use is surprisingly close to your code. You'd want to use `order=True` to generate `__gt__` &c.

Comment: You would get a better answer at codereview, but on first glance to_tuple could be used a lot. getitem is not used at all so delete it. You don't need to sort inside create_persons_list. You don't really need separate variable and getters. And what CharlesDuffy said re: dataclass

Comment: As an alternative to dataclasses, [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) is also worth being aware of, particularly when the objects you're creating are intended to be immutable (which may not be so much the case here).

Comment: (The other thing that can prevent you from creating work for yourself is [the YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), expanded on at https://wiki.c2.com/?YouArentGonnaNeedIt -- to assume that "you aren't gonna need it" for functionality that you don't have immediate utility for. Code you don't write is code you don't have to maintain and debug, and that people trying to read and understand your codebase don't need to review; there's a lot of value to keeping things simple).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can make the code more concise.

1. Instead of a series of 'if-elif' statements in the '**getitem**' method, you can use a dictionary to map indices to attributes.

   ```
   def __getitem__(self, index):
       attributes = {0: self._name, 1: self._age, 2: self._weight, 3: self._height}
       if index in attributes:
           return attributes[index]
       raise IndexError("Index out of range")
   ```
2. Instead of having separate conditions for each sort key, you can use a dictionary to map sort keys to corresponding lambda functions.

   ```
   def create_persons_list(n=10, sort_key='height'):
       key_mapping = {'name': 'get_name', 'age': 'get_age', 'height': 'get_height', 
                      'weight': 'get_weight'}
       key_func = lambda x: getattr(x, key_mapping.get(sort_key, 'to_tuple'))()
       return mergesort([Person(np.random.choice(NAMES), np.random.randint(18, 
                        101), np.random.randint(150, 201), np.random.randint(45, 
                        101)) for _ in range(n)], key=key_func)
   ```

Comment: Welcome! This is a good answer, but maybe to a not-so-great question. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and its guidance to only answer questions that fit within Stack Overflow's topicality and scope guidelines (which the 1st, 4th and 5th bullet points all touch on).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).